# Redirect my output to textarea

Tags: java, hadoop

I am doing data analysis using hadoop using java on eclipse ,I am get my output log as shown in the below image on eclipse, how can we redirect it to a text area..

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851234/system-out-to-a-file-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are mostly counters and progress so, have a look at
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995543/how-to-get-the-mapper-output-byte-counter)
and [JobClient's API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html).

Also, I think you will find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203785/logging-the-output-of-a-map-reduce-job-to-a-text-file) very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class JTextAreaOutputStream extends OutputStream {

private JTextArea destination;

public JTextAreaOutputStream(JTextArea destination) {
    if (destination == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Destination is null");

    this.destination = destination;
}

@Override
public void write(int b) throws IOException {
    write (new byte [] {(byte)b}, 0, 1);
}

@Override
public void write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length) throws IOException
{
    final String text = new String (buffer, offset, length);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable ()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                destination.append (text);
            }
        });
}
}
```

Then Redirect you text area like this:

```
public void setSystemOutRedirect() {
    JTextAreaOutputStream out = new JTextAreaOutputStream (textAreaUpgraderLog);
    System.setOut (new PrintStream(out));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(out));
}
```

Comment: I am not giving the output they are generated automatically, so it doesnt help

Comment: its only printing the data i.e given by me in system.out.print() i want the log file to be printed..

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following snippet at the beginning of your program.

```
File file = new File("D:/out.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(fos);
        System.setErr(ps);
```

then all Standard err will be redirected to `D:/out.txt` file. 
For redirecting standard output just use `System.setOut(ps)`